# Secure laravel api

Tags: laravel, api, security, https, laravel-passport

I have implemented api with laravel
I use passport for authentication

I need to allow only my apk to request this api

Can any one help me with an idea

I use https but is there any other secure method

Comment: You'll never be able to achieve this 100%; people can decompile the APK and figure out how you're protecting it. You can defeat *casual* explorers in a variety of ways, like sending a custom user agent for your API calls and rejecting calls that don't use it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a passport client. Any other requests to your API other than from the approved client, will be rejected by the API.

You can find information to setup a client [on this link](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/passport#managing-clients)

Comment: Try not to answer with links too much. If possible, try to create a short summery of what the link solves and concentrate your summary on the solution only.

Comment: Thank you @dbf. Will do so in subsequent answers. Appreciated.

Comment: Yo cheers ... ;)